# How to get screen width in landscape mode in react native

Tags: react-native, styles

I want to make some components in React Native to have width of screen in both portrait mode and landscape mode. Currently I get it for portrait in the styles like this:

`width: Dimensions.get('window').width`

but this doesn't work for landscape. When I switch the device, the width of the component doesn't cover the width of the screen in landscape. It is half the screen.

Please how do I get it to fill the screens width?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following

```
_onLayout = event => console.log(event.nativeEvent.layout); // width, height, x, y

 // On your Wrapper
 <View onLayout={this._onLayout} />
```

As mentioned in the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view.html#onlayout)

```
{nativeEvent: { layout: {x, y, width, height}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

In portrait mode, you can set the width to window's width and height, something like:

```
width: Dimensions.get('window').width
```

However, in Landscape mode, the width and height of the window get interchanged. Hence, in this case, you would have to set the width to:

```
width: Dimensions.get('window').height
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using functional components, you can use the `useWindowDimensions` hook, which will return updated values when the orientation changes.

```
import {useWindowDimensions} from 'react-native';

const {width, height} = useWindowDimensions();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Dimenstions.get('window').width` use use react native's `useWindowDimensions()` hook. This provides the actual width of portrait or landscape mode screen.

```
import { useWindowDimensions } from 'react-native';
const {width} = useWindowDimensions();
console.log({width})
```

Answer (score -1):

if knowing the screen width in `render` is enough for you, just use `Dimensions.get('window').width` inside your `render` method. The result of this call will change with orientation.